# What is the difference between an impulse and a force related to a physics engine?

Tags: c++, 2d, physics

What is the difference between an application of an impulse and an application of a force in relation to a physics engine?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

An impulse is applied instantly, so it does not depend on the time step. You would use an impulse when you want to give a fixed boost of speed to something, or the physical action happens too quickly (ex. bullets/gun ricochet, collisions, jumps, instant speed ups).

Meanwhile a force changes the speed directly proportional to the time step. You use it for things that have an over time effect (ex. gravity, long springs, air resistance).

Mathematically `impulse = force * time`; And for reference `impulse = mass * velocity_change`, `force = mass * acceleration`.

If you expand the first, you can check this:

- `impulse = force * time` ->
- `impulse = mass * acceleration * time` and since `acceleration * time = velocity_change` ->
- `impulse = mass * velocity_change`.

Comment: Since `impulse = force * time`, the impulse is also time dependent (at least if you use forces to get the impulse's magnitude). Indeed, momentum or impulse is useful for applying instantaneous dramatic changes. The most popular example comes from the laws of conservation of momentum and energy: http://www.physics.ohio-state.edu/~gan/teaching/spring99/C10.pdf.

Comment: So is the implementation by `Jeff Lake` via `Game Coding Complete 3rd Ed. Chapter 15: Collision and Simple Physics` incorrect: (paraphrasing) `Start with a Vector3d (or 2d depending) of forces F, Accumulate all Forces applied in a list, Accumulate All Impulses in a list add both totals to Forces, empty Impulses list, Accel = F / mass, Vel += Accel * deltaTime, Pos = Vel * time.`

Comment: @Casey: that is how I do it. In my simulator I can't use the rigid body case where two bodies collide and everything works out directly. Following the Newtonian way of integrating the acceleration to find the velocity and then the position. My impulses are derived from a repulsion force (response/reaction force is a synonym in my understanding): `i = F_response * DTime`. You can go either ways: use the `i` impulse to correct the velocities after the collision, or use directly the response force. If you get the impulse from somewhere else, you canconvert it to an `F_response` and it works OK.

Comment: @teodron Thanks, that brings up a separate question which I'll ask ...separately. :P